# Systemd Execstart

Tags: python, systemd

I have a Python script which I want to run as a daemon. I am doing that by creating a unit file `/etc/systemd/system/service`

and I want to run it as `systemctl start/stop/restart myservice`

and depending on this `start` `stop` arguments I am handling system signals like `SIGUP`,`SIGINT`

Problem is i can run my script as Python `main.py` start/stop/restart and my logic works.

But after converting into a unit file this python file is invoked by `ExecStart` and I don't know how to pass arguments there?

```
    [Unit] 
    Description=This service monitors docker daemon for events
    After=multi-user.target

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/home/PycharmProjects/python_tests/service-discovery/utils/auto_registeration_script/main.py
    User=root
    WorkingDirectory=/home/PycharmProjects/python_tests/service-discovery/utils/auto_registeration_script/
    Restart=on-failure

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What kind of arguments are you trying to pass? you could just append them to the `ExecStart` line if you know them beforehand, or use environment vars as another way of configuring the service

Comment: I wanna take start/stop/restart from CMD of systemctl and pass it to execstart as arguement to my python script so that my script can run based on the arguement came in

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to do this @omu_negru

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that you are actually running "main.py start" and "main.py stop"? In that case you have programmed a "forking" service.

```
[Unit] 
Description=This service monitors docker daemon for events
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=script=/home/PycharmProjects/python_tests/service-discovery/utils/auto_registeration_script/main.py
ExecStart=$script start
ExecStop=$script stop
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/PycharmProjects/python_tests/service-discovery/utils/auto_registeration_script/
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```